# How to add a http POST value in objective-c when the key or value has special chars?

Tags: objective-c, http

I'm attempting to do an http POST that has a key containing a $ char and wanted to know if I'm submitting it correctly

here is the http POST in httpfox (RAW)

&__EVENTTARGET=ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24btnSearch

here it is the plain txt format (notice the $ chars)

ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSearch

but in my string I couldn't get a valid post doing something like this

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.localhost.com/someurl.aspx"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

    NSString* theBodyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"__EVENTTARGET=ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSearch"];
    NSData *requestData = [theBodyString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    //other request details ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to URL encode theBodyString. Try:

```
NSString* theBodyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"__EVENTTARGET=ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSearch"];
NSString* escapedUrlString = [theBodyString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSData *requestData = [escapedUrlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

or (in response to the comment)

```
NSString* theBodyString = @"2010 19:32";
NSString* escapedUrlString =  (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (CFStringRef)theBodyString, (CFStringRef)@" ", (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]", kCFStringEncodingUTF8 );
escapedUrlString = [escapedUrlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
```

Comment: so should I leave the $ in and do the encode before I create the requestData (NSData) ?

Comment: This actually didn't work - for example: I need this value __CLIENTTIME=3-4-2011+18%3A2 but with your approach of stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding I get this instead __CLIENTTIME=3-4-2011%2019:34

Comment: Thats a strange one alright. The %20 is actually valid and I'm guessing that the ":" is ignored as its actually valid in a URL (coming after the http:). Not 100% on how to get a space to encode into a plus but dropping back to Core Foundation you can get that colon to encode. Updated above.